# Linked list of structures in c

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

I am attempting to create a linked list that has data that points to a structure but am having trouble creating a node.

```
 typedef struct n_data{
     char name[16];
     int integer;
} DATA;

typedef struct node{
    DATA * data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

typedef struct{
     int num;
     NODE *head;
}ROOT;
```

I have the function make node that returns a node that has data that points to a DATA structure:

```
NODE *makeNode(DATA *d){
    NODE *temp;
    temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if(temp != NULL){
        temp->data= d;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

And my main looks somewhat like this:

```
int main(){
    DATA* newdata=(DATA*)malloc(sizeof(DATA));
    strcpy(newdata->name,"Hello");
    newdata->integer=7;

    NODE * temp;
    temp = make_node(newdata);
}
```

I am getting error

warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong so can anyone help me with this?

Comment: In the main, temp = make_node(newdata);

Comment: `make_node` != `makeNode`.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the help I totally missed that.

Comment: `DATA* newdata=malloc(sizeof *newdata);` and `temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);`

Comment: I assume you use gcc. Add the -Wall option, it enables "all" warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your code

change line `temp = make_node(newdata);` to `temp = makeNode(newdata);`